# Как открыть несколько шаблонов в новых вкладках Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin

В django admin панели я хочу отмечать записи чекбоксами и в Action dropdown есть кнопка `Print` которая передает информацию в шаблон. Я хочу что бы каждая отмеченная запись открывались в отдельном шаблоне и в новой вкладке.

**admin.py**

```
@admin.register(Salary)
class SalaryAdmin (admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('worker', 'salary_uah', 'dates')
    search_fields = ('worker', 'salary_uah', 'dates')
    list_filter = ('worker', 'date')
    actions = ['button']


    def button(self, request, queryset):

        select = request.POST.getlist(admin.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME)
        for i in select:
            return '<a  target="_blank" href="{}"></a>'.format(reverse('act', args=[i]))

    button.short_description = 'Print'
    button.allow_tags = True
```

**views.py**

```
def acts (request, obj):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('admin:login')
    salary = Salary.objects.get(id=obj)
    workers = Worker.objects.filter(id=salary.worker.pk).values()
    salary = Salary.objects.filter(id=obj).values()
    return render(request, 'zpapp/act.html', {'workers':workers, 'salary':salary }
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',home, name='home'),
    url(r'^add/$',add_worker, name='add'),
    url(r'^act/(?P<obj>[\w-]+)$',acts, name='act')
```

Помогите решить данную проблему

Comment: у вас в button цикл в любом случае один раз сработает, начните с этого)